# Display with alert the values stored in ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel, knockout-3.0

My application has many items in the viewModel and I would like to see those values displayed in an alert box so I can see what is actually stored in there.  When trying to pass this view model back to my controller I am not seeing any values, instead I am getting an error that 'viewModel' is not defined.

Here is an example of my view model script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function ViewModel() {

        var self = this;

        self.SectionId = ko.observable("");
        self.SectionName = ko.observable("");

        var SectionNames = {
            Id: self.SectionId,
            Name: self.SectionName
        };

        self.selectedSectionName = ko.observable();
        self.SectionNames = ko.observableArray();

        // Initialize the view-model for Work Sections
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSections", "Home")',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                self.SectionNames(data);
            }
        });

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);     
});
```

Similar to creating a global variable or class level variable I would like to have this viewModel contain all of the current values for all of my observable items.

Comment: from your indentation you are calling a new instance of view model in the view model.  doesn't that need to be instanciated outside of the function?

Comment: it looks like you didn't close the tag of the function

Comment: I just copied the javascript so don't worry about the closing tag...

Answer (score 0):

Except for the missing closing tag (as mentioned by @CSharper) your code will *not* throw the error you speak of. The answer to your question lies either in that missing closing tag, or in another piece of code not shown.

Here's how you can check, by mixing your code (+ closing tag) with a `$.ajax` stub:

```js
$.ajax = function() {}; // Noop stub.

$(document).ready(function () {
    function ViewModel() {

        var self = this;

        self.SectionId = ko.observable("");
        self.SectionName = ko.observable("");

        var SectionNames = {
            Id: self.SectionId,
            Name: self.SectionName
        };

        self.selectedSectionName = ko.observable();
        self.SectionNames = ko.observableArray();

        // Initialize the view-model for Work Sections
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSections", "Home")',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                self.SectionNames(data);
            }
        });
    }
      
    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
$root = <code data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></code><br />
No errors on console.
```